# itemprop refering to an outer itemscope

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I have an itemscope for an event containing a table with attendees.

I would like to be able at the same time to have the table as `itemscope itemtype="[...]Table"` and the rows of the table as `itemprop="attendee"` referring to the outer `itemscope itemtype="[...]Event"`. Something like:

```
itemscope itemtype=Event
    itemprop something about Event
    itemprop another thing about Event
    itemscope itemtype=Table
        itemprop=attendee referring to the Event, not the Table
        ...
```

However if I use what I have written above the `attendee` property will refer to the `Table` scope. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The question [How do I have an itemprop nested in one itemscope actually be applied to a different itemscope?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16700765/1591669) seems to be same and it contains an [answer with a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16725422/1591669).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could probably do that with `itemref`. That allows you to refer back to a previously specified bit of microdata using an `id` on the relevant element. Specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-microdata-20110405/#attr-itemref

Comment: Note that in the example case, the `attendee` property would then be applied to both, the Table *and* the Event.