# Sharing properties between parent and child itemscopes when using Microdata

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am using Microdata to mark up a blog post.  I have come across a problem and I am unable to find a solution with Google.

In short I want to use a property already specified in a nested itemscope for the parent itemscope too.

I've simplified my code to the example below, I want to use the author image as the image for the blog post.

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2016-02-25" />
  <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Test Organisation">
    <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <link itemprop="url" href="#" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="#" />
  <div class="heading">
    <h2 itemprop="name headline">Imported Article 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="author-aside" itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <img itemprop="image" src="#" />
    <div class="name" itemprop="name">Author Name</div>
    <div class="role" itemprop="jobTitle">Job Title</div>
  </div>
  <span itemprop="articleBody">
    <p>Body Content</p>
  </span>
  <br />
  <span content="2016-06-30" itemprop="datePublished">Thursday 30th June 2016</span></article>
```

I've tried to use the answer indirectly suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700765/how-do-i-have-an-itemprop-nested-in-one-itemscope-actually-be-applied-to-a-diffe) under the comment "CODE I NOW HAVE" which does what I need it to but produces a new error:

> The attribute itemtype has an invalid value.

I am using [this service](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) to validate the Microdata.

Comment: Note that your `span` element (with the `datePublished` property) is invalid because it [can’t have a `content` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669). You should use a `time` element (with its `datetime` attribute) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two separate issues involved.

#### Solution for your Microdata

To add the `image` property from the `Person` item also to the `BlogPosting` item, you can use the `itemref` attribute:

1. Give the `image` property (in `Person`) an `id` attribute.
2. Add the `itemref` attribute to the element with the `BlogPosting` type, referencing the `id` value.

Example:

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemref="author-image">

  <div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
    <img itemprop="image" src="#" id="author-image" />
  </div>

</article>
```

#### Solution for Google Rich Snippets

While the above mentioned markup is valid Microdata and appropriate use of the Schema.org vocabulary, Google has additional rules/restrictions for getting one of their Rich Snippets (or Knowledge Graph features) displayed.

In Schema.org, the [`image` property](http://schema.org/image) can have a URL or an `ImageObject` item as value, but Google wants to see an `ImageObject` for their Rich Snippets.

(Just like you did it with your `logo` property.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clear, concise and informative answer.  I've been switched to another project for a couple of days but will accept the answer as soon as I am able to test it.  I hope an upvote will do for now.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Worked exactly as you suggested, thanks also for the general advice.